# removing spaces between shaded frames and within it

Tags: spacing, boxes, shading

I have written a a few latex lines to mimic the shaded boxes shown in the below picture:
[image]

However, my result so far looks like the following:
[image]

which doesn't look completely like the above image.

My lines are as follows:

```
\definecolor{bright_blue}{RGB}{31,127,198}
\definecolor{dark_red}{RGB}{176,31,31}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{246,243,226}
\begin{shaded*}

\textcolor{dark_red}{\textbf{SUMMARY: }}
     
    Some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
    , some text, some text, some text, some text.
    , some text, some text, some text, some text.
    , some text, some text, some text, some text, some text.
    
    \definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{239,244,243}
    \begin{shaded*}
        \textcolor{bright_blue}{\textbf{RESULTS: }}
        
        Some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
        , some text, some text, some text, some text.
        , some text, some text, some text, some text.
        , some text, some text, some text, some text, some text.
    \end{shaded*}
\end{shaded*}
```

Does anyone know how I can make it more similar to the first image?
In addition,how can I add the current chapter number like the above image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this "shaded*" environment comes from framed.sty.

Best not to put one inside the other, but instead one after the other. Then the question becomes: how to prevent a gap between the two shaded environments.

The "extra" space can be eliminated by setting `\OuterFrameSep`, which is a parameter for framed.sty.

The remaining gap can be removed by suppressing the baseline skip. For this use a TeX command `\nointerlineskip` (which may not be officially LaTeX-ese).

```
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{246,243,226}
\setlength\OuterFrameSep{0pt}
\begin{shaded*}

\textcolor{dark_red}{\textbf{SUMMARY: }}
     
    Some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
    , some text, some text, some text, some text.
    , some text, some text, some text, some text.
    , some text, some text, some text, some text, some text.
\end{shaded*}
\nointerlineskip  
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{239,244,243}
\begin{shaded*}
    \textcolor{bright_blue}{\textbf{RESULTS: }}
        
    Some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
        , some text, some text, some text, some text.
        , some text, some text, some text, some text.
        , some text, some text, some text, some text, some text.
\end{shaded*}
```

Oh, the remaining difference in appearance is due to`\parindent` and `\parskip` (you should choose a style consistently throughout the document).

Answer (score 3):

A small improvement, manually adjusting the vertical spacing between the two shaded environments to make the blank space completely disappear.

For the problem of the chapter number,n you have the `\oldstylenums` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bright_blue}{RGB}{31,127,198}
\definecolor{dark_red}{RGB}{176,31,31}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{246,243,226}
\begin{shaded*}

\textcolor{dark_red}{\textbf{SUMMARY: }}

    Some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
    , some text, some text, some text, some text.
    , some text, some text, some text, some text.
    , some text, some text, some text, some text, some text.
\end{shaded*}\vspace*{-\dimexpr\FrameSep + \baselineskip +1pt}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{239,244,243}
\begin{shaded*}
    \textcolor{bright_blue}{\textbf{RESULTS: }}

    Some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
    , some text, some text, some text, some text.
    , some text, some text, some text, some text.
    , some text, some text, some text, some text, some text.
\end{shaded*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Improvement by changing automatic to manual adjustment?

Comment: @DonaldArseneau: For me, `\nointerlineskip` results in a blank line. I found no other way to remove it. I tried top play with  lengths defined in your package, but there remained  a thin white line. Maybe there's a trick, but I didn't find it.

Comment: That is weird. I'd be interested in your test and log file, because I don't see how it could happen.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau: Certainly. Can I mail them somewhere?